# English idiom or proverb equivalent for "if everybody is doing it, I will also do it"

Tags: idioms, proverbs

Can somebody please help me by giving an English idiom or proverb equivalent for:

> If everybody is doing it, I will also do it.

Comment: There are many, many possibilities. Please can you give a sentence that shows precisely how you wish to use the expression?    If  possible give an example sentence with a gap where the phrase should go.  Otherwise you will simply get a string of guesses and you won't know whether they will fit with your context.

Comment: I'll give the famous example from *Catch-22* - Q: "Suppose everyone thought the same way you do?" A: "Then I'd be a damn fool to think any different."

Comment: Perhaps of interest to some: the psychological phenomenon of doing what others are doing often arises due to [*diffusion of responsibility*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility), a.k.a. *groupthink*, where a person in a crowd feels less responsible for his actions since he is not singled out as a significant actor. This can result in *mob rule* and *vigilantism*.

Comment: I've heard something along the lines of '2 million people can't be wrong, right?' but I don't have any other info to make a full answer.

Comment: A clarification might be needed. Are you talking about some individual's *desire* or *natural instinct* to follow the crowd? Or are you talking about the *necessity* (or *advisable behavior*) to do what others do/to blend in? Or are you talking about *unavoidable consequence* of living among "everybody" and gradually becoming "just like them" regardless of whether one wants to?

Comment: This is actually a syllogism: if everybody is doing it, you (and I) will already be doing it. [Otherwise it wouldn't be everybody.]

Comment: If all your friends jumped off a bridge, would you do it too?  :)

Comment: "If you can't beat 'em, join 'em?"

Answer (score 54):

"When in Rome," short for "When in Rome, do as the Romans do," could work. It expresses the notion of doing what everyone else does, though it perhaps more justifies than describes such a situation.

Comment: +1 it sounds like the asker wants something where the person feels their following the crowd is the right thing to do, and this is good for that

Answer (score 51):

The two phrases that spring to mind are ["follow the crowd"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/follow+the+crowd) and ["jump on the bandwagon"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/jump+on+the+bandwagon).

> **follow the crowd**: to do what everyone else is doing; go along with the majority; do what most others are doing
>
> *I am an independent thinker. I could never just follow the crowd.*
> *When in doubt, I follow the crowd. At least I don't stand out like a fool.*
>
> - [*[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/follow+the+crowd)*]
>
> **jump on the bandwagon**: to support something that is popular
>
> *Publishers jumped on the CD-ROM bandwagon even though they didn't know if they could sell CD-ROMs.*
>
> - [*[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/jump+on+the+bandwagon)*]

Comment: But in simple everyday parlance it would be *I'll go along with the rest*.

Comment: It's worth noting that "follow the crowd" is fairly neutral, while "jump on the bandwagon" is somewhat negative, it implies a grasping desperation to do the popular thing, bask in reflected glory or jump on a passing trend. If you want to make "follow the crowd" more negative, try "follow the herd", which makes it more docile and unthinking. If you want to make it positive, you could try something like "follow the [wisdom of the crowd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom_of_the_crowd)"

Comment: Monkey see, Monkey do

Answer (score 42):

Consider, [***go with the flow***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+with+the+flow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20with%20the%20flow%3B%2Cc0) and ***follow the herd***.

> go with the flow: also, ***go with the tide***. Move along with the prevailing forces,
> accept the prevailing trend, as in *Rather than striking out in new
> directions, I tend to go with the flow*, *or Pat isn't particularly
> original; she just goes with the tide*. The flow in the first and more
> colloquial term, which dates from the late 1900s, alludes to the ebb
> and flow of tides and probably gained currency because of its
> appealing rhyme. [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+with+the+flow)
>
> : to do what most other people are doing or agree with their opinions [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+with+the+flow)
>
> follow the herd: to do what other people do [McMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/follow-the-herd)

Comment: +1 it sounds like the asker wants something that portrays the crowd-following in a positive way, and "go with the flow" is a good option there

Comment: +1, and i would like to add that i often hear "i'm easy going" too.

Answer (score 17):

Two idioms often used in English are *like lemmings* and *like sheep*

The *Cambridge Dictionary* defines *[like lemmings](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like-lemmings?a=british)* as

> in a ​silly way, without ​thinking, and in ​large ​numbers:
>   *People ​rushed like ​lemmings to ​invest in the ​company.*

One of *Oxford Dictionary Online's* definition of *[sheep](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sheep)* is

> A person who is too easily influenced or led:
>   *the party members had become sheep, and she refused to be taken in*

Both of these terms are highly negative.

Similarly, the phrases *herd mentality* and *run with the pack* suggest going along with a group, often in a blind, conforming way.

A common parental challenge to a child who wishes to do what everyone else is doing is *[if all your friends jumped off a bridge, would you do it too?](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/If_All_Your_Friends_Jumped_Off_A_Bridge)* (*Uncyclopedia*)

(The usual response is silence, not to be confused with agreement that the parent is correct.)

Comment: +1 for " not to be confused with agreement that the parent is correct".

Comment: For the final paragraph, [this XKCD is an important counter-argument](https://xkcd.com/1170/)

Answer (score 9):

**Herd Mentality**  or **Mob Mentality**

> [Herd Mentality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_mentality), or [Mob Mentality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_mentality), describes how people are influenced
>   by their peers to adopt certain behaviors, follow trends, and/or
>   purchase items. Examples of the herd mentality include stock market
>   trends, superstition and home décor

Comment: Also known as ***"groupthink".***.   n_n

Comment: It's worth mentioning that all of these (including groupthink) are very negative terms. You'd be unlikely to explain your own actions as being "herd mentality" or similar unless you were at least partially ashamed of them and wanted to distance yourself (e.g. "why did you dress like that when you were a teenager?" or "why did you loot that shop?")

Answer (score 8):

What you're describing may be [peer pressure](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/peer-pressure).

Comment: @A.P.  That should be an answer!  -- YOINK! --

Answer (score 8):

I like to say "all the cool kids are doing it"

Comment: This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 8):

Consider "Follow Suit"

> 1. Games To play a card of the same suit as the one led.
> 2. To do as another has done; follow an example.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/follow-suit

Comment: This doesn't imply "everybody else" or "majority". You can follow suit by following one man's example.

Comment: True, but it is definitely taking a cue based solely on precedent.  It may suit the OP's need.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider Paul Simon’s line “[Who am I to blow against the wind?](http://genius.com/2255378),” but for me (and the linked Genius[dot]com annotation), “blowing against the wind” connotes more a feeling of ‘doing something that is futile’ than one of ‘doing something different from everyone else.’

However, combining the “Who am I to …” part of Simon’s line with an idiom that better captures the notion of doing the opposite of [most] other people (e.g.,  “go/swim against the tide” [which is, I've just noticed, the negative version of an answer already given by Elian]) would, I think, capture the notion that you’re describing:

> **[Who am I to go/{swim} against the
>   tide?](https://books.google.com/books?id=fqPlEMyugtAC&pg=PT7&dq=%22who+am+i+to+go+against+the+tide%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAGoVChMI7Z36ndz5yAIVCMFjCh0IXwaH#v=onepage&q=%22who%20am%20i%20to%20go%20against%20the%20tide%22&f=false)**

(example of usage from ‘Confessions of an S & M Virgin’ by Linda Jaivin via Google Books)

> **[go/swim against the tide](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+against+the+tide)**:
>
> to do the opposite of what most other people are doing It's not easy
>   to go against the tide in defence of your principles. (sometimes + of
>   ) He always seemed to be swimming against the tide of public opinion.

(from Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed. Via ‘The Free Dictionary’)

Answer (score 4):

"Keeping up with the Joneses" is another way of saying it.

see this link for more information
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keeping_up_with_the_Joneses

Comment: I think this only really applies to the acquisition of material goods and status. You wouldn't describe, say, dropping litter on an already badly littered street as "keeping up with the Joneses".

Answer (score 3):

Consider **"to run with the world"**:

> to do what is popular, **follow the crowd**.

[image]

([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=LVCyDcQy6L8C&pg=PA444&lpg=PA444&dq=%22run%20with%20the%20world%22%20idiom&source=bl&ots=FSi0yGI4Td&sig=tWdM2dyz3NI3KOGhmg-2R3_ODfU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCGoVChMIko62o6n5yAIVht9yCh3DKQwh#v=onepage&q&f=false))

In addition, there's a well-known phrase ["Fifty million Frenchmen can't be wrong"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty_Million_Frenchmen) that can also be used to justify **going along with the crowd** through an appeal to majority. It can also be adapted to fit the situation, e.g. *A gazillion of Elvis fans can't be wrong.*

Comment: I'm in my mid-40's and I've never once heard the expression "run with the world". [Edit: Until now.]

Answer (score 2):

Monkey see. Monkey do! AT least, that's the one that comes to my simple mind first.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**10,000,000 people can't be wrong!**  (Substitute 10,000,000 for whatever suitably large number you choose.)  Admittedly, this can be used for other cases, where people just believe a thing, rather than do a thing, but it works that way too.

(Mind you, I believe that it's absolutely possible for 10,000,000 people to be wrong, but that's beside the point.)