# A phrase/expression/saying for coming in an already-stablished situation and so accept it for granted

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, popular-refrains

You become a member of a particular society/community, and there are certain norms/conventions/lifestyles in that community which you take for granted and don’t question. Sometimes they are unreasonable or even nonsensical. But you don’t question them, maybe because there were already there when you came to the community.

> **Example**: when we started our university time, these rules were already
> there for a long time. So I guess we took them for granted. After some
> years, during the campus protests, some students started to question
> such rules, and then we were surprised how long we had simply accepted
> such ridiculous rules without questioning them.

Is there an expression/phrase/idiom in English to say that going into some contexts that already existed, and is not simply changeable, or objectionable?

Comment: "unquestioning acceptance of the status quo" or "unquestioningly accepting the status quo" or "naive acquiescence"

Comment: @Prem I think the term ‘status quo’ can be developed into an answer. The term ‘naive acquiescence’ with a reference. I’ve seen just ‘silence acquiescence’.

Comment: I have Posted the Expanded Answer based on my Comment , @Sasan , I hope it is useful !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [English idiom or proverb equivalent for "if everybody is doing it, I will also do it"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285112/english-idiom-or-proverb-equivalent-for-if-everybody-is-doing-it-i-will-also-d) ('follow the crowd/herd'; 'go with the flow'; 'not swim against the tide'; 'be sheep' ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are a couple of Ideas or Concepts involved here :**

> The Current Situation (as it exists)

> The unwillingness (or inability) to change

> The inability to  think (about alternatives)

> Blindly accepting (or following) the norms

> Herd mentality (to follow established rituals)

---

---

**We could use the Concepts to make the necessary phrase. Eg :**

> "unquestioning acceptance of the status quo"

> "unquestioningly accepting the status quo"

> "naive acquiescence"

> "passive acceptance"

> "blind acceptance"

> "following the unthinking herd"

---

---

**Individual Idea or Concept or Word references :**

[status quo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20status%20quo) :

> the current situation ; the way things are now

[naive](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/naive/definitions) :

> lacking information or instruction

[acquiescence](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/acquiescence/definitions) :

> acceptance without protest

[unquestioning](https://www.wordwebonline.com/en/UNQUESTIONING) :

> Not inclined to ask questions

[herd mentality](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/herd%20mentality) :

> the tendency of the people in a group to think and behave in ways that conform with others in the group rather than as individuals